# Missing assembly when running functions locally

Tags: c#, azure-functions

When running my Azure Function (C#) locally i get these error messages:

> A ScriptHost error has occurred
>       The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DefaultTrace' threw an exception.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.TraceSource, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

But I've added the assembly

[image]

Is there any black magic to getting it to work locally?

Comment: Try upgrading `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` to `1.0.7`. And specify which framework / runtime your are running on.